# ASP.NET Web API in Azure: Customize authentication filter to prevent brute force?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-authorization

I've got a website from the VS2013 SPA template (web api 2.2) which leverages ASP.NET Identity 2.1, and everything works really well. My controller methods look like this:

```
    [Authorize]
    public Api.Models.Widget Get(int widgetId)
    {
    var requestingUserId = Int32.Parse(Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IdentityExtensions.GetUserId(User.Identity));
    ...

}
```

It works as expected:

- Unauthorized users aren't granted access
- After an authorized user gets in, I can obtain their user ID

But **I now want to modify the application to prevent excessive API requests. I plan to check to see if that particular userID had made a certain number of requests within a certain timeframe. I'm looking for suggestions for the best place to do this.**

I would like not to have to repeat this logic in every controller, and it seems like an action filter might be the best place. But as this will need to read the userid and I'm not sure if the order of filters is guaranteed, it may also make sense, if possible, to derive the filter which is already being called for authorization and to add my extra logic.

I'm wondering if anyone could give an example of doing something similar? It seems that instead of "authorize", it would be in a custom authentication filter, and I'm not sure how I would tie this together.

Thanks for any suggestions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several filter options:

> **Authorization filter**
>   Makes security decisions about whether to
>   execute an action method, such as performing authentication or
>   validating properties of the request.

Example:

```
public class WebApiAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute 
{
    public override async Task OnAuthorizationAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        base.OnAuthorization(actionContext);

        Guid userId = new Guid(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId());

        // ...here your validation logic 
    }
}
```

> **Action filter**
>   Wraps the action method execution. This filter
>   can perform additional processing, such as providing extra data to the
>   action method, inspecting the return value, or canceling execution of
>   the action method

To minimize the impact on your server, you can cache any http get request in the user browser for a predefined time, if the user request the same URL in that predefined time the response will be loaded from the browser cache instead of the server.
As OutputCache Attribute is not available for Web API, you can use [this Output caching in ASP.NET Web API post as alternative](http://www.strathweb.com/2012/05/output-caching-in-asp-net-web-api/) or you may implement your own Action filter attribute for Caching:

```
public class CacheFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the cache duration in seconds. The default is 10 seconds.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The cache duration in seconds.</value>
    public int Duration
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public CacheFilterAttribute()
    {
        Duration = 10;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(FilterExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        if (Duration <= 0) return;

        HttpCachePolicyBase cache = filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache;
        TimeSpan cacheDuration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Duration);

        cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
        cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.Add(cacheDuration));
        cache.SetMaxAge(cacheDuration);
        cache.AppendCacheExtension("must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate");
    }
}
```

**Additional Considerations**

Once the user makes a call against your web api, you will have to add +1 to the counter and then use this counter to check massive calls with the same user in a timeframe. The problem here is where to store this counter.

If you store the counter in a RDBMS like SQL Server, every user call will perform a DB access. This could become a performance problem. This storage should be as light weight as possible. So using a NoSQL db might be a good approach.

Comment: "This storage should be as light weight as possible. So using a NoSQL db might be a good approach." Yeah, good call. Since this is in Azure, I planned to use Azure Table Storage for this. Thanks for your helpful response!

Comment: @BenjiFB I agree that such fine grained session state tracking is not a job for SQL Server but I am not sure Azure Table storage is either. My hunch is that an Azure Redis cache would be an order of magnitude more performant in this case. I feel this throttling initiative is turning into a mini project just for a perceived need. Bear in mind the truly malicious user could swamp your system and cause it to hang on those out of process session frequency checks particularly if async-await coding practice is not used.

Answer (score 4):

I think that you are looking after is a filter that will throttle the requests made by your users so you should check WebApiThrottle https://github.com/stefanprodan/WebApiThrottle

This should do what you aim to do or you can check out the source code to customize it four your needs